# How can I detect an empty line in a text stream and print everything below it?

Tags: c, string, websocket

I am trying to use strcmp and fgets to read line by line to detect "\r\n".
I'm working in a program with websockets and I want to show the HTML code in my console that it is written in the socket.

```
  while( ( n = read(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1) ) > 0 ) {
    buffer[n] = 0;
    FILE *fp = fdopen(s, "r+"); 
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)!=){
    if (strcmp(buffer,"\r\n")==0){
      fputs(buffer,stdout);
    }
    else{
      printf("error\n");
    }
```

Comment: When you read from the stream with `read()`, that input won't be available if you then use `fgets()` to read from the same stream.

Comment: Have you run this code in a *debugger* and examined the content of `buffer` after that `read` call (before any `fgets`), which seems to be a little importance to your posted code, but likely *highly* important to your goal and the related underlying data handling?

Comment: I would strongly recommend against parsing HTTP without using a library. It looks like a simple protocol, but with all kinds of extensions, encodings and compression, it isn't.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes and the content that wanted is all in the variable `buffer` the problem is in the function `while` i guess.

Comment: I am sure that `buffer` is not my issue because before that i could print all the text in my console.